# pg_dump Command Issue

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I have been using pg_dump for a while and every time I try to run the same script I seem to get issues. Not sure if it is user error or something to do with updating to Postgres 11.

Here is my command

```
pg_dump --dbname=postgresql://username:password@localhost:5432/DatabaseName --data-only --column-inserts -t "\"HoldingValuesTemp\"" > holdingValues.sql
```

This throws the error

```
pg_dump: too many command-line arguments (first is "HoldingValuesTemp\")
```

I think the issue has to do with the table name, it is case sensitive and is HoldingValuesTemp.

I tried to break it down into another pg_dump

```
pg_dump -d DatabaseName -p 5432 -U username --data-only --column-inserts -t "\"HoldingValuesTemp\"" > holdingValues.sql
```

Which gives the same error

So I also tried

```
pg_dump -d DatabaseName -p 5432 -U username --data-only --column-inserts -t '"HoldingValuesTemp"' > holdingValues.sql
```

after entering the password I get `pg_dump: no matching tables were found`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try this: `pg_dump -d DatabaseName -p 5432 -U username --data-only --column-inserts -t "HoldingValuesTemp" > holdingValues.sql`

Comment: Same issue, no matching tables found. I even tried this, I ran the following command `psql --host localhost --port 5432 --username username DatabaseName` entered my password and ran a `select * from "HoldingValuesTemp;` and it output the table contents. So I know it can access the table, and my connection is correct just not sure why this command is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try to qualify the table name with the schema:

```
-t '"MySchema"."HoldingValuesTemp"'
```

There is also the possibility that you have a space character or similar in the table name.

Comment: same issue, "no matching tables were found"

Comment: Maybe some weird character in the table name.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was more of a workaround than a solution.

The issue had to do with the table name, not sure why it was not finding that table but I assume it had to do with case sensitivity.

Solution:

Rename the table with a prefix that I looked up with a wildcard.

Table was "HoldingValuesTemp" I updated it to "ts_HoldingValuesTemp"

then ran the following command

`pg_dump -d DatabaseName -p 5432 -U username --data-only --column-inserts -t 'ts_*' > holdingValues.sql`

making it backup all tables that begin with "ts_"